# Get content of another window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm totally lost here. I want to grab the visual content of a window for further processing, inside my console application. I know how to find the HWND, but from that I don't know what to do to get the content. The application I want to grab is 3D, but I don't know if its Direct3D or OpenGL, but I need to process every frame (some frame skipping would be acceptable though)

Thanks!

Comment: Try to investigate its inner structure further with Spy++.

Comment: Do you just need an image of the rendered window or do you need it's content?

Comment: I just want the image, to perform image processing. But as I mentioned, the application is 3D, so there are no windows forms.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look into the `BitBlt()` function. If you're not familiar with the Win32 GDI, the way to proceed might seem unintuitive. Take a look at this [`BitBlt()` Copy and Paste tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Bitblt_wrapper_class.aspx). The article doesn't present the whole code, and it's VB.net, but the outline of the method is presented (Window Handles, Graphics Contexts, `BitBlt()` and their relashionships).

If this question is still unanswered in a few hours I'll post a more precise, C++ oriented answer then (I don't have the code with me right now).

Comment: It grabs the current contents of the window, whatever is there, including whatever the 3D application rendered in it. I helped a friend write a bot for a 3D game once using OCR in part of the captured frame.